# Application using apache commons config

Tags: java, apache-commons

Can anybody let me know about a couple of open source projects that uses apache commons config library (http://commons.apache.org/configuration/). This will enable me knowing the best practices on using this library and to get to know the library quicker.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, reading the users guide will be a good idea http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/user_guide.html

Comment: for sure, however, knowing at least one single open source project that uses this library would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [quick search](http://code.ohloh.net/search?s=org.apache.commons.configuration&browser=Default&pp=0&fl=Java&fe=java&mp=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&ff=1&filterChecked=true) on code.ohloh.net returns a lot of hits with usage examples.

Comment: Thanks so much, at last I found it. I like the DefaultConfigurationService.java in apache turbine project. Thanks again.